# FBSDKLoginError.m No known class method for selector 'bundleForStrings'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to build an iOS Application that uses the Facebook SDK to implement a "Login with Facebook" feature.

I'm trying to setup the `FBSDKLoginKit` in my project and running into a problem. When I build the build fails in `FBSDKLoginKit` with this error:

> FBSDKLoginError.m No known class method for selector 'bundleForStrings'

I get the `FBSDKCoreKit` and `FBSDKLoginKit` frameworks via Cocoapods. My Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'FacebookAccessTokenTest' do
  pod "FBSDKCoreKit", "4.1.0"
  pod "FBSDKLoginKit", "4.7.0"
end
```